# Error compiling INET framework for omnet++

Tags: linux, omnet++, inet

I am attempting to compile the most recent INET 3.3.0 on OMNeT++ 5.0. I am running Arch Linux `Linux arch 4.5.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 11 22:21:28 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Note that this worked for me on my laptop also running Arch Linux. On my desktop it fails however.

OMNeT++ is installed and works, I can run the example projects with no problems.

When I compile INET however, it always fails. I have tried letting the IDE do it all by itself by answering `yes` to its offer to install the latest INET. I have downloaded it myself, imported as a project, rightclicked and let it `build project` and I have resorted to going into the INET directory, issuing `make makefiles`, `make MODE=release -j4`, but it all leads to the following error:

```
inet/common/serializer/ipv4/IPv4Serializer.cc:410:129: note: in C++11     destructors default to noexcept
inet/common/serializer/sctp/SCTPSerializer.cc
inet/common/serializer/tcp/TCPSerializer.cc
inet/common/serializer/udp/UDPSerializer.cc
In file included from     inet/common/serializer/sctp/SCTPSerializer.cc:28:0:
./inet/common/serializer/sctp/headers/sctphdr.h:415:22: error:     flexible array member in union
         uint8_t info[];
                  ^
```

Previous versions of INET lead to different errors, none work. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is the GCC version number on the system? This seems to be a C++ compatibility problem. Probably GCC is tool old?

Comment: Nope, gcc is version `gcc version 6.1.1 20160602 (GCC)`. If anything it might be too new?

Comment: Yep. Inet was not tested with GCC 6.x

Comment: I will downgrade gcc and try with an older version. Do you know which version is definitely supported?

Comment: I have installed gcc49 from the AUR and attempted to tell the Makefile to use its binary by issuing make CC=gcc-4.9 (that's the binary provided by the gcc49 package). To no avail. Could be that the Makefile is not using the CC variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have just to modify the code in the `sctphdr.h` and make it

```
  uint8_t info [128];
```